# Not able to read application.properties file using Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im newbie in java and trying to read values from application.properties file
here is the code

```
@Service
@Component
@Configuration
public class ReadTest {
    
       @Value("${product.page.size}")
        public  Integer pageSize;
    
       @Autowired   
    public Integer getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    @Autowired   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ReadTest r = new ReadTest();
        
        System.out.println(r.getPageSize());

    }

}
```

Im getting output as null.
not able to understand where is the problem. I read the docs but no luck

references :
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/read-values-from-application-properties-file
https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

please suggest . Is this the write approach ?

**EDIT 1**

I modified the entire code . Here is the Latest one :

**ValueresourcesApplication.java**

```
package valuetest.valueresources;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ValueresourcesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ValueresourcesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ValueTest.java**

```
@Service
@Configuration
public class ValueTest {
    
      @Value("${product.page.size}")
        private static Integer pageSize;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.out.println(pageSize);

    }

}
```

Now , when Im running the main method of ValueTest , the pagesize value is not getting printed.

Please help

Comment: I see no spring boot application here, only plain Java app

Comment: @Antoniossss
please see the edit 1 . Using spring Initializer , created springBoot application .

Comment: Still there is NO SRPING BOOT APP bootstraping in your `ValueTest` class. Having `ValueresourcesApplication` somewhere in your classpath means literally nothing.

Comment: Sorry , not getting @Antoniossss. Can you please helm me in code

Comment: Run `ValueresourcesApplication` not `ValueTest`